# error upload db to mysql

Tags: mysql, key

```
-- Constraints for table `variation`
--
ALTER TABLE `variation`
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `variation` (`id`),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`scale`) REFERENCES `scale` (`id`),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`user`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`);

--
```

error

> ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 277: Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails (`getsy`.`#sql-f44_2a`, CONSTRAINT
>   `#sql-f44_2a_ibfk_2` FOREIGN  KEY (`scale`) REFERENCES `scale` (`id`))

this table variation

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `variation` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scale` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `parent` (`parent`,`scale`,`value`,`user`),
  KEY `scale` (`scale`),
  KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=101 ;
```

help me ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that in `variation` table column `scale` contains values that are missing in table `scale` column `id`.

You can check missing values with following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.scale FROM 
   variation AS a LEFT JOIN scale AS b ON a.scale = b.id 
WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: when i try query show result 11 and this warning
Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

what can i do ?

Comment: If you get result - 11, this means that you have scale ID in variation table, but you don't have the same ID in the scale table. Please read about foreign keys here: [create-table-foreign-keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).